# Connect to python development django server from a non-local network machine

Tags: python, django, networking, webserver

I am able to run my django dev server on my machine and make it accessible to the local network by running:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver IP:80
```

OR

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now, how can I make my server accessible over the internet by a machine not in my local wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

Use your machine LAN/WAN ip address, then configure your modem/router to let this ip have external access.

For example, considering your machine LAN/WAN ip address is `192.168.0.100`.
You run your django development server as `python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.100:8000`.

An then, set up your modem/router.. Probably inside your DMZ settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Here you can find a detailed usage description: http://www.lexev.org/en/2014/remote-url-localhost-server/